# RecordRTC FileSize and Tracking Problems for asp.net MVC 5 app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, webcam, webrtc, video-recording

I am building an application for ASP.Net MVC 5, in which I need to record a live video and audio stream from the webcam/microphone. I have decided on a web app based solution, [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/). I have used the demo from, [Muaz-Khan's](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-ASPNETMVC) github as a starting point, and modified it for my specifications.

The problem I am having is that I am unable to determine how to reduce the size of the webm that is being created. Right now it is about 1.7MB a second, my goal is for it to be 4-10MB a minute.

Also the file that is created from this does not possess time metadata, meaning I cannot use the seek-bar to go to a specific time. i.e. it says 3 secs have elapsed 0 remain, and still runs.

Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: I am aware that support for the below code will only work in Firefox. I will simply wait for Chrome to add support, and therefore have removed the workaround Muaz Khan has in the demo.

```js
< script >
  //script 1
  document.createElement('article')< /script>


<script>
//script 2
        function PostBlob(blob, fileType, fileName) {
            / / FormData
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);

// progress-bar
var hr = document.createElement('hr');
container.appendChild(hr);
var strong = document.createElement('strong');
strong.id = 'percentage';
strong.innerHTML = fileType + ' upload progress: ';
container.appendChild(strong);
var progress = document.createElement('progress');
container.appendChild(progress);

// POST the Blob using XHR2
xhr('/Video/PostRecordedAudioVideo', formData, progress, percentage, function(fName) {
  container.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
  var mediaElement = document.createElement(fileType);

  var source = document.createElement('source');
  source.src = location.href + 'Files/' + fName.replace(/"/g, '');

  if (fileType == 'video') source.type = 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"';
  if (fileType == 'audio') source.type = 'audio/ogg';

  mediaElement.appendChild(source);

  mediaElement.controls = true;
  container.appendChild(mediaElement);
  mediaElement.play();

  progress.parentNode.removeChild(progress);
  strong.parentNode.removeChild(strong);
  hr.parentNode.removeChild(hr);
});
}

var record = document.getElementById('record');
var stop = document.getElementById('stop');

var audio = document.querySelector('audio');

var recordVideo = document.getElementById('record-video');
var preview = document.getElementById('preview');

var container = document.getElementById('container');

var recordAudio, recordVideo;
record.onclick = function() {
  record.disabled = true;
  navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
      mandatory: {
        googEchoCancellation: false,
        googAutoGainControl: false,
        googNoiseSuppression: false,
        googHighpassFilter: false,
        sampleRate: true
      },
      optional: []
    },
    video: true
  }, function(stream) {
    preview.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    preview.play();

    //var legalBufferValues = [256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384];
    // sample-rates in at least the range 22050 to 96000.
    recordAudio = RecordRTC(stream, {
      onAudioProcessStarted: function() {}
    });
    recordAudio.startRecording();

    stop.disabled = false;
  }, function(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t'));
  });
};

var fileName;
stop.onclick = function() {
  record.disabled = false;
  stop.disabled = true;

  preview.src = '';

  fileName = Math.round(Math.random() * 99999999) + 99999999 + ".webm";

  recordAudio.stopRecording(function(url) {
    preview.src = url;
    PostBlob(blob, 'video', fileName);
  });
};

function xhr(url, data, progress, percentage, callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      callback(request.responseText);
    }
  };

  if (url.indexOf('/Video/DeleteFile') == -1) {
    request.upload.onloadstart = function() {
      percentage.innerHTML = 'Upload started...';
    };

    request.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
      progress.max = event.total;
      progress.value = event.loaded;
      percentage.innerHTML = 'Upload Progress ' + Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100) + "%";
    };

    request.upload.onload = function() {
      percentage.innerHTML = 'Saved!';
    };
  }

  request.open('POST', url);
  request.send(data);
}; < /script>
```

```html
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Video Record"; }
<--Script 1 goes here-->
<!-- script used for audio/video/gif recording -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/RTCRecording")
<article>
  <section class="experiment">
    <p style="text-align:center;">
      <video id="preview" controls style="border: 1px solid rgb(15, 158, 238);"></video>
    </p>
    <hr />
    <button id="record">Record</button>
    <button id="stop" disabled>Stop</button>
    <div id="container" style="padding:1em 2em;"></div>
  </section>
  <--Script 2 goes here-->
</article>
```

Comment: You should use [MediaStreamRecorder.js](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) with `recorder.audioChannels=1` to get half size of recorded WAV without loosing the quality.